# Appending many mysql_fetch_array results

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, foreach

1. while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { echo $row['sth']; .....}

   2. $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      while($row) { echo $row['sth']; .....}

When I change first while loop to second, I get an infinite loop. Is there a way I can do `fetch_array` before the while loop and not get an infinite loop?

The reason I'm trying this is...:

So I have `select multiple name=options[]` delivered through `$_POST`.
Then I am using `foreach($_POST['options'] as $option)` to SELECT indexes whose field value matches `$option`. After that, if I do a while loop as in `1.` from the above, I only get the elements of the last `options[]`.
So I want to append the results of `mysqli_fetch_array` to an array `$row` and then do a while loop as in `2.` But I get an infinite loop like said.

I know my explanation is a bit confusing.... If it isn't clear up to this point, read more below. I am explaining in more details with more codes provided.

```
========================================================================
if(isset($_POST['options'])) {
    foreach($_POST['options'] as $option) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE stdYr = '$option'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query) or die("Error in ".$query."<br>".mysqli_error($db_conx));
        }
    }
}
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {}
```

With this code, when an array options[option1, option2, option3] is passed, for example, the result only outputs the elements of options[option3]. Query output of option1 and option2 is overwritten in foreach loop.
So I came up with an attempt to declare `fetch_array` inside foreach loop and append in to $result like this:

```
========================================================================
if(isset($_POST['options'])) {
    foreach($_POST['options'] as $option) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE stdYr = '$option'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query) or die("Error in ".$query."<br>".mysqli_error($db_conx));
            $row.=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
        }
    }
}
while($row) {}
```

**BUT** this results in infinite loop.....

Can someone help? Let me know if this doesnt make sense... Thanks ! :D

Comment: Something tells me that your design got something wrong. Usually I really despise queries inside a loop. What I usually do is populate what I need before (like getting a list of IDs) and then execute another query using IN (youridshere). Last but not least, if data is not extremely huge I prefer to collect it in arrays and then used in other queries and so on. PS: SANITIZE your $_POSTs too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use do-while instead of while. That way you can move the first `mysql_fetch_array()` call out of the loop:

```
<?php
    // code
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row) {
        do
            echo $row["sth"];
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result));
    }
    //code
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you are always overwriting your variable inside the loop. Use it as an array.

**EDIT:** My fault, I've added the result as an array, not the row.

Change this:

```
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $option) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE stdYr = '$option'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query) or die("Error in " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($db_conx));
    $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

(added the `[]` after the `$row`, so now it's `$row[]`. Outside of the loop, says `var_dump($row);`

After this, you can set up a new `foreach` loop. Do not add the while loop to it.

Comment: This exacrly is my problem. Ill give iy a try and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: After changing to $result[], I get  `mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result`error message on `while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))`.

Comment: Check my edited post, sorry, that was my fault. I've added the result as an array, not the row. And rename the `$row` to `$rows` everywhere :)